# Why is my browser so much faster than my console application?

Tags: c#, json, rest

I am trying to load test my JSON REST API, however, I've noticed some strange results.

I built a quick load tester console app, it uses `System.Net.WebRequest`, but it reports much slower times than when I hit the API with chrome.

```
var r = WebRequest.Create("https://myapi.com/stuff);
var startTime = DateTime.Now;    
using (var response = r.GetResponse()) { }
var stopTime = DateTime.Now;
```

According to Chrome's debugging tools, from sending to response, it consistently takes about 15ms

According to my program, my minimum time is 50ms, and my mode time is 60-70ms.

What am I doing wrong in my console app that makes requests so slow?

Thanks

Comment: what happens if you start the timer after creating the web request, just before getting the response?

Comment: Try using [`System.Diagnostics.StopWatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) instead, see if you are still seeing a difference in time.  I believe its more accurate

Comment: Do you get the same performance if you run without debugging?

Comment: you might have keep alive on in the browser so it doesn't have to do all the TCP crap.

Comment: Tried using `stopwatch` and moving start time to just before getting the response, no difference

Comment: Your testing results can't be treated as reliable.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Never claimed they could be

Comment: Whaaaat?!  A C# helper function isn't as fast as a web browser that's built solely to browse the web and is supported by millions of developer dollars?!  ::mind blown::

Comment: I wonder if `HttpClient` would be an improvement over `WebRequest`

Comment: At least move creating of `WebRequest` object out of measure scope and use `StopWatch` instead. Try several times and calculate arithmetic mean.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan already did, no noticeable difference

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer try using HttpClient, but use a shared static instance.

Comment: I am leaning torwards @DanielA.White's comment, it is tcp keep alive

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer you could use something like wireshark to see if this is the case or not.

Comment: Eric Lippert blog post on the precision of `DateTime`: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/04/08/precision-and-accuracy-of-datetime/